# How to trip my trap, python text Adventure

Tags: python, text, adventure

I spent the afternoon building a trap tile function for my textRPG after several questions on here I'm getting down to the actually implementing the function. iv adapted it from my EnemyTile function where it tracks is alive by if the enemy has hit points greater than zero. My TrapTile has an is_tripped function that is supposed to be true or false. i thought i had wrote the function to trip when the player enters the room but that isnt the case. how would i trip this TrapTile. Github repo

https://github.com/GusRobins60/AdventureGame.git

```
 class TrapRoomTile(MapTile):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.trap = items.Trap
    r = random.randint(1,2)
    if r == 1:
        self.trap = items.PitFall()
        self.trap.is_tripped()

        self.set_text = "The floor in this hallway is unusually clean."
        time.sleep(1)

        self.tripped_text = "The open hole of a Pit Fall trap obstructs the tunnel."
    else:
        self.set_text = "Looks like more bare stone... "
    super().__init__(x, y)

def modify_player(self,player):
    if self.trap.is_tripped():
        player.hp = player.hp - self.items.damage
        print("You stumbled into a trap!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\nTrap does {} damage. You have {} HP remaining.".
              format(self.items.damage, player.hp))

def intro_text(self):
    text = self.tripped_text if self.trap.is_tripped() else self.set_text
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return text
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add a question, the problem you are having, and a desired outcome of your problem to your "question".

Comment: Did you fix it?  The github code looks correct: `self.trap.tripped = True`

Comment: well, i am officially completely baffled. I was struggling with errors last night attempting to initiate the trap with self.trap.tripped = True. closed everything down packed up the laptop when I turned it back on and loaded everything up this morning it worked as expected... The only thing i can think of is a file wasn't saved somewhere.